# Can't create the post. Try again later [Google +]

Tags: android, google-plus

What is wrong with my URI.

In below code when I pass

**Uri uri=Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/restaurant");**

Then google plus show me **post successful**

but when I try to post with this  uri

**Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.com/css3020/xxxx/files/video/13.mp4");**

then google+ give me error message **Can't create the post. Try again later** .When I check google + account the **post has created then why google+ showing this error**.

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText(""+video.getVideoName())
            .setContentUrl(uri)

            .getIntent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to a html/text document that embeds the mp4 video. Not the video file itself.

Comment: In my application I have uploded mp4 file on my server and a link is created...I just want to share that link on google+ ..I don't want to embed a video file at sharing time.

Comment: G+ has a select number of partner sites for whom they support embedding videos directly in the stream. You will have to embed your video in an HTML document you host and then share that webpage.

Comment: Thanks for reply @abraham please tell me one more thing..On google plus I just want to share link..and it is shared successfully no problem..but it shows me error dialog..I don't want stream support on google+ page.So what should I do if I don't want to embed video on a web page..Is there any other option?